# Problems with \nocite

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am writing my thesis in LaTex and I have problems with the bibliography. I would like to write all the references I put, also the ones not cited into the text. I tried to use the command `\nocite{*}` but when I use it it indeed shows all the references, but in the text the citations are like [?] without numbers. It does it correctly but without all the references when I do not use the command.
The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,mt]{ethidsc} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{emptypage}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  
%chapters....
\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

The references are in the bibliography.bib file written like

```
@article{C2014,
author={Author},
journal={Journal C},
title={First Paper},
year={2020}
}
```

Any idea how can I solve the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: you are not really showing what you are doing, your example has neither a cite nor a \nocite command. Normally it should work after some compilation runs, but imho \nocite along with an unsorted bibliography doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to compile your document a couple of times:

- `pdflatex` → `bibtex`/`biber` → `pdflatex` → `pdflatex`

There is no `\backmatter` in report classes, so I commented that part out. I've also removed the now unnecessary `fixltx2e`-package.

The following example runs without problems:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{C2014,
author={Firstname Lastname},
journal={Journal C},
title={First Paper},
year={2020}
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{Me, I, and all my other Personalities}
\author{Me I. Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  

\chapter{First Chapter}
\kant[1]

\section{Here be a Citation}
This is the best article ever written: \cite{C2014}

% \backmatter
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: citation]

[image: bibliography]